# Is there any benefit to using the following approach to calculate the number of ways of dividing 52 cards into 4 indistinguishable groups of 13?

Tags: combinatorics

The answer is of course (52!/(13! 13! 13! 13!))/4!
What about the following approach?  Let f(n, k) denote the number of ways of distributing n/k cards to each of k indistinguishable piles.  We want to find f(52, 4).  We know that one pile must contain the 7 of diamonds.  We can therefore uniquely characterize the distribution by the 12 cards included with the 7 of diamonds and the distribution of the remaining 39 cards to the 3 other piles.  We get the recurrence relationship of f(52, 4) = C(51, 12)*f(39,3), since C(51, 12) is the number of ways of choosing the 12 other cards included with the 7 of diamonds.  By making further use of the recurrence, we get f(52, 4) = C(51,12)*C(38,12)*C(25,12)*f(13,1), where f(13,1)=1.  This could be written as a very compact algebraic expression. Other than that, does it have any usefulness?

Comment: I mean... it is good to think about these sorts of things and come up with different expressions.  This is beneficial for actually calculating the result since you can keep the numbers smaller and more manageable to avoid using such absurdly large numbers as $52!$ in the calculation (*so long as you do similarly smart things with the binomial coefficients*).  It isn't particularly beneficial if just looking at the expressions on paper however.  Certainly not *hurtful*, but it doesn't do much in the way of giving insight that we didn't have otherwise.

Comment: As for better phrasing and formalizing your result, the 7 of diamonds was a poor choice.  It is better to have used at each stage "*the smallest as-of-yet unused card*" or similar where we have a defined total order for the cards, such as $2\clubsuit<2\diamondsuit<2\heartsuit<2\spadesuit<3\clubsuit<3\diamondsuit<\cdots$

Comment: This works, and gives the same result because: $$\binom{52}{13}\binom{39}{13}\binom{26}{13}=\frac{52}{13!^4}$$ and $$\binom{52}{13}=4\binom{51}{12},\\\binom{39}{13}=3\binom{38}{12},\\\binom{26}{13}=2\binom{25}{12}$$ I'm not sure how it would be "useful."

Comment: Thanks all.  It seems like such a pretty result.  It is a shame that there is nothing that can be done with it.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.